# Convert Canadian census subdivision polygons to WKT (4326) using ogr2ogr?

Tags: ogr2ogr, well-known-text

We've got a large dataset that is in 4326. I'd like to integrate Canadian CSD data from the [statcan website](https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2021/geo/sip-pis/boundary-limites/index2021-eng.cfm?year=21) into it. But the polygons are in a coordinate system that I don't recognize. Probably Canvec 3347?

For instance the polygon for Dolphin Island looks like:

```
POLYGON ((3847646.5171429 2694041.15714289,
3847662.23428575 2694027.20857146,
3847669.29428575 ...)
```

Can I convert this to 4326 to match the rest of my data? Searching for this on google yielded nothing that used ogr2ogr directly and a lot of it was >8 yrs old.

Comment: `ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:3347 -t_srs EPSG:4326 new.shp old.shp`

Comment: thanks, I'll give it a shot -- what should I have googled to find that? I'm inexperienced with GIS stuff

Comment: That worked, put it up as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) to reproject vector data using something like this:

```
ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:3347 -t_srs EPSG:4326 new.shp old.shp
```